# Spark-shell command throwing error

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, cloudera

i am trying to open spark shell by using `$ spark-shell` it was working every time but today suddenly it is throwing this error  :

**Error**

```
WARN util.Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.
```

Comment: There are several ways to check currently listening ports. Have you tried `netstat`?

Comment: @cricket_007 is right. you can try `sudo netstat -apen`

Comment: `tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4040                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      501        183535     7070/java`


`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4041                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      501        200465     11112/java `
this is what i am getting.

Comment: @eliasah the `u` and `t` are redundant with the `a`, but I would throw an `l` for listening in there

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks !

Comment: now what should i do ? should i kill those pid as @eliasah mentioned

Comment: no. you'd better confirm with the ps command what these processus actually are

Comment: @Captcha It's a **warning**, not an error. Everything should run just fine, isn't it the case ? If you want you can kill the previous Spark UI as suggested in the comments

Comment: @cheseaux it is not at all opening the scala shell, it is getting stuck there

Comment: Then just kill the process listening to port 4040 or if you don't know what you are doing maybe a simple reboot could solve your problem right away

Comment: I rebooted my system and checked still the same issue is there. May be i should kill it.

Comment: you should indeed kill it if you don't need it anymore

Comment: `spark 485 0.3 0.9 1593728 148388 ? Sl 04:27 0:22 /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera/bin/java -cp /var/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process/488-spark_on_yarn-SPARK` this is what i am getting when using `ps aux`

Comment: @Captcha Please see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could kill the process listening to port 4040 if you don't need it anymore

```
fuser -k -n tcp 4040
```

or you could start a new spark-shell using another port if you need both instances

```
spark-shell --conf spark.ui.port=4048
```